# ACS 5.2 : configure activities feeds and notifications

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

On my ACS 5.2 instance, activities feed notifications are disabled in GlobalProperties.

I have to find a way to send an email to specific users (4) when documents are created or uploaded on a site repository, ON A WEEKLY BASIS.

I can't use simple rules on folders because of the weekly notification.

I've read many things about this. I will be able to modify GlobalProperties to enable notifications and add a cron.

But I don't understand how/if it is possible to limit this to one site and to only specific activities.

Could you help me with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you can :

- configure which type of activity is emailed (preview, download...) in a properties file
- customize the cron job sending activity feeds

But you can't :

- reduce the email feeds just to only one site (user has the capability to enable/disable feeds for each site he wants to follow)

So, to resume, I think you have to create your own cron job by developing. The good news is that it should be very close from the original global activity feed cron job.

Maybe I forget another way to resolve your problem.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But do you knkw where I can find the "standard" files where mail notifications are sent ?

Comment: You have to search in alfresco source code for that. There is the Git of the editor for that : https://github.com/Alfresco. You will have to search in "alfresco-repository" project, I think. Be careful, you have to search for sources of the  good version of Alfresco; the one you're using.

Comment: You can also create a Maven "all-in-one" project in an IDE like Eclipse an explore Alfresco Java source code supplied as a dependency.